# Access denied when writing to a file. Why?

Tags: asp.net, permissions

I've developed an ASP.NET v4 web app which I am trying to get to write to a folder in the webroot.

For the life of me I cannot get Windows 7 to allow it to write a file, I get Access is Denied error each time.

What I have tried on the folder is

```
attrib -r /foldernameandpath
attrib -r -s /foldernameandpath
Removing Check from ReadOnly attribute in folder properties
Changed owner to folder to current user whom is also the admin
Changed owner to Everyone
Adding Everyone user to folder with all permissions
Changing the folder to the Public Document directory
Changing to the root of the C drive (Out of desperation)
```

Nothing seems to work and all I want to do is test that the write works.

Now I know the system works and writes fine cause I had this same web app on a second machine writing the PDFs to the C drive without issue. This second machine I just cannot get it to allow the write.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh please for the love of all things holy, put the keyboard and mouse down and stop what you are doing. Some of the actions in your list seriously frightens me.
All the things you list as your actions are most likely useless or desperately random at best.
As a web developer, you shouldn't have to start messing around changing ownership of folders, especially not the web root folder normally used by the web server. When you do, you'll end up in a dark, cold and lonely place. Lord only knows what other desperate measures you have taken. For your own sake, I'll recommend you to do a system restore or even system reinstall to make sure you are in a healthy state.

Let's go back one step and try to sort out what you are doing.
First: what is the path you are trying to write to?
Second: are you running this application directly from within Visual Studio or in IIs?

If you are doing the first option then your current user account is the account who tries to write to the path in question. Do you have write permissions there?
One thing you can try is to start Visual Studio with elevated permissions and see if that works.
If you are running in IIs, it the associated pool account that needs write permissions.
Are you doing impersonation by any chance? If so, make sure the impersonated account have proper permissions.

You should only write to a predefined folder within your app path, like ..\App_Data for example.

The easiest way to find out which account you are running with and determine what path you are trying to write to, is to fire up `SysIntenals` [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and find the entry with the `access denied` result. Select properties for that entry and find out which account tried to do the write action. When you have determined that, right click on the folder in question and give the proper account write permissions.

Comment: +1 Sometimes we get so obsessed with what we want the outcome to be, that we stop thinking about what we are doing. Most likely he is using Visual Studio and the OS is not letting him write the file.

Comment: First off. The OS is in VMFusion version of Windows 7, so the environment is safe. I installed this one in particular for the app to test at home. 
Secondly the environment it will be hosted on will not be public, it will be a single Windows 7 machine and the web app is simply to allow the person using it to produce a large number of PDFs with data on it.
Thirdly, this is not normal practice (The wholesale bumbling about with permissions thing) for me, I was simply getting frustrated with the fact that I could not get it to write a file.

To answer Hanlets comment. Yes correct on both counts.

Comment: Using Impersonation, no.

To boil my question down to the absolute basics. How do I allow the ASP.NET web app to write to a folder on Windows 7 when Windows 7 permissions seem impossible?

Why cant a person who is logged in as an administrator on the PC simply change the read/write permissions. I realise its to protect people against themselves but in this instance I just needed temporary read/write to test some code.
When the app is handed over the network admin will install it and choose the folder for the PDFs to be written to.

Comment: Also, it will not write to the App_Data folder either. Even added IIS_USER permission to the folder via IIS and this had no joy.

Comment: Well then, what does Process Monitor tell you? This should to be a simple matter of cause and action. PM will tell you the cause and the action is to remedy it. Don't use your sledge hammer methods, a fine detailed tweak should be sufficient.

Comment: Monitor says user is IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
Process: w3wp.exe
Operation: CreateFile
Result: Access Denied

App pool the web app is using is: DefaultAppPool with identity of ApplicationPoolIdentity.

Not knowing much about permissions etc I can only assume the ApplicationPoolIdentity falls under user IIS_USERS and have checked this user has permission to Write and Execute to the folder.

Comment: Ok. Thanks Magus. App Monitor has helped. Added IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool to the permissions for the folder via IIS, recycled the apppoll and restarted the website and it is not writing the files. Many thanks and apologies if this whole process was like pulling teeth. Not seeing the user IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool in the user list under computer management did not help though and neither did my lack of knowledge with Windows permissions. Thanks again.